# NoMethodError in Users#new Creating Simple Login with rails

Tags: ruby, railstutorial.org

Newbie to rails here. Confused as to why I am getting a NoMethodError in Users#New undefined method `users_path' for #<#:0x00000101a5e4a0>

Model Class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save { self.username = username.downcase }
    VALID_INPUTS = /[[:ascii:]]+/
    validates :username, presence: true, length: { maximum: 128 },
        format: { with: VALID_INPUTS }, uniqueness: true
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { maximum: 128 },
        format: { with: VALID_INPUTS }
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

Users Controller Class

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
  end
  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

New View (new.html.erb)

```
<h1>Users#new</h1>

<%= form_for(@user) do |u| %>
    <%= u.label :username %>
    <%= u.text_field :username %>

    <%= u.label :password %>
    <%= u.password_field :password %>

    <%= u.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
    <%= u.password_field :password_confirmation %>

    <%= u.submit "Create Account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The error is in the view, specifically I think I call the form_for() method on a nil object. This exact same syntax is used in the Hartl tutorial though and it works fine so I'm unsure what to do. Thanks in advance. Apologize if this is dumb.

Comment: form_for, when called with an unsaved object, will look for users_path.  Have you set this route up in your config/routes.rb file?

Comment: Could you add your routes.rb file?

Comment: Please also add the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I figured an answer but am not sure as to why it works? I basically needed to edit my db/routes.rb file and added

```
resources :users
```